# What backer board should I use in shower ceiling?

Tags: shower, waterproofing, cement-board, backer-board

I'm tiling my shower up to about 7' and the rest of the shower and ceiling will simply be painted. What material should I use on those?

I am using RedGard as my waterproofing method so there will not be any waterproofing BEHIND the backer board.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a backerboard on shower ceilings - especially if you aren't tiling it.  You can drywall it.

If you do use a backer board I would suggest Hardieboard.  You would then just put a skim coat of joint compound (mud) over and sand.

Comment: One reason I like cement board is simply because it can fit into my car easier with the 3x5 sheets :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with this.  Just usually can't line up the backerboard and drywall widths as easy so a little more work on that side...  You can cut your drywall before you put it in your car.

Comment: Always use MR (moisture resistant) drywall in the shower area.  I'd take DMoore's advise and cut it so it will fit in your car. Of course, cut it large enough to do the job if possible so you don't have extra joints to deal with if possible.